# Mysql Many-Many Relationships

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

How to insert, update, delete data with **many to many relationed table** of MYSQL?

E.g.:

```
**Structure of my database**
table A -    ID, Field1, Field2, ...
table B-     ID, Field1, Field2...
table Refer- ID, AID,BID
```

Is there any automatic reflects system in refer table when insert data in tables A or B?

For Example:

If I insert data in `Table A` with corresponding data in `table B` it will automatically reflects in Refer table based on `Table A` and `B` Relationships.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look on below url for more detail and examples.

http://www.select-sql.com/mysql/how-to-merge-2-tables-into-one-result-in-mysql.html

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/11/auto_increment-and-merge-tables/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

- delete part you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185811/mysql-on-delete-cascade-test-example)) but the ENGINE used should be InnoDB but then again you can use a trigger for delete also
- for inserts and updates you can use triggers ([example](http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/11/12/mysql-trigger-how-to-example-tutorial-and-syntax/),[docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html))