# how to delete from another 2 table using one key?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql

I have a table named
Category_tbl

```
Id
Categoryname
info
```

subcategory_tbl

```
id
categoryid
subcatname
info
```

product_tbl

```
id
subcat
info
```

i in here subcategory_tbl has the category id and product_tbl has subcategory id as subcat.now if i want to delete a category then i all the corresponding data of same key in subcategory_Tbl and product_tbl needs to be deleted.how can i do it?i tried joining but its not working

Comment: First delete the data from the tables which have foreign key and then the table with primary key..Using multiple delete statements....

Comment: i didnt use any foriegn keys now is there any way?

Comment: You mean to say that subcat of product_tbi is not the foreign key?? and so is the category_id of subcate_tbi??

Comment: Try cascading for the below given link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: exactly thats what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the data from the tables which have foreign key and then the table with primary key..Using multiple delete statements...

Answer (score 0):

Without [cascading deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185811/mysql-on-delete-cascade-test-example) on the foreign keys, what you can do this as a sequence of deletes from `subcategory` through `product` and finally `category`. Assuming you wish to delete category 123:

```
delete 
from product_tbl
where subcatid in
(
  select id
  from subcategory_tbl
  where categoryid = 123
);

delete 
from subcategory_tbl
where categoryid = 123;

delete 
from Category_tbl
where id = 123;
```

If however you do have `ON DELETE CASCADE` defined on both foreign keys, all you would need to do is delete the category and the product and subcategories would be deleted as well. Dangerous, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately their isn't a way to `delete` in the way you are asking..As the tables are `not related to each other in any manner`..Just by having a column with equal values to other table, one cant associate the `delete` command to delete the rows of both the tables...

There has to be some criteria by which we can join the tables and then delete the rows..which we do not have here...